# Test Coverage with ReSharper, MSpec and dotCover

Tags: resharper, code-coverage, mspec, dotcover

Consider this controller method from an ASP.Net MVC3 project:
[image]

Having run dotCover code coverage, the Details method has clearly been covered by a test, as indicated by the green highlighting (arrowed).

However, when I try to use ReSharper to navigate to "covering tests", it reports no coverage:
[image]

dotCover clearly knows which tests have covered the code, as shown in the ReSharper test runner:
[image]

So did I miss something? Shouldn't ReSharper be able to tesll me which tests covered a particular statement? Did I find a bug? Should I report it against dotCover, ReSharper or MSpec?

Comment: Where in the test is it covered? If it is in a set-up/tear-down phase then it may not be considered to be covered by a test - perhaps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unfortunately a [known bug with dotCover](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DCVR-2658) and it's not clear from comments to this bug report whether the problem is going to be fixed anytime soon.

BTW "Navigate to covering tests" is dotCover's functionality, not ReSharper's.

Comment: I had submitted my issue as RSRP-292366 before you led me to yours. I tried to link them but YouTrack won't let me. With two teams involved, maybe we will get some traction.

Comment: I received a reply from someone at jetbrains that says, basically, that because MSpec tests are different from a 'normal' testing framework, they would need changes on the MSpec side to support this feature. Any of the MSpec devs know anything about this?